# Can't access external sdcard in Android application

Tags: android, file-io, java-native-interface, android-6.0-marshmallow

I am trying to create a file in external storage (sdcard) of my android device and perform read and write operation in that file. But i am not able to access sdcard through my application.

I am using android marshmallow.

I give the permission in my menifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

When i use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` it give me the `/storage/emulated/0` path, in which i can successfully read and write.

But i want to perform read and write in my external sdcard which is mounted at `/storage/6161-3432`. and in that i am not able to perform such operation.

I also try with JNI code which can open file and perform operation in specific path. here also i can access my `/storage/emulated/0` path but not access my sdcard path `/storage/6161-3432`.

So how can i access external sdcard with my application?

Comment: What is the version of OS your are using for testing the application? If your emulator/device having OS greater than 23>= then you have to assign the permission dynamically.

Comment: `assign the permission dynamically`. There is nothing to assign. You need code to ask the user of the app to confirm the permission.

Comment: `i want to perform read and write in my external sdcard`. If you use one of the answers you will be able to read and write only in that specific directory of the sd card. For the rest of the card you can only read. No permissions needed.

Comment: I have a update here that i used runtime permission for external storage but i cant create any file/folder inside SD card through my application. When i use hard code path for my SD card then it seems that app can read SD card path but not able to create new files. And i am able to create file/folder through `adb shell`. So i don't know why i can't create file from my application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following code it will give you list of all Possible storage option in your phone:--

```
  File[] filesDirectory = context.getExternalFilesDirs(name);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried your way but  `File[] filesDirectory = context.getExternalFilesDirs(name);` not worked in my Android Studio. So i use `File[] filesDirectory = getBaseContext().getExternalFilesDirs("/storage/XXXX-XXXX");
    for (int i = 0; i < filesDirectory.length; i++)
    {
     Log.d(TAG, "FileName:" + filesDirectory[i].getName());
    }`. But i can't get my SD card path.

Comment: On Which Android Version you are testing.

Comment: Or tried with  File[] Dirs = ContextCompat.getExternalFilesDirs(MyApp.GetContext(), null);

Comment: Hey Thank you very much, I am able to write into sd card using your suggestion. it gets me write into `/storage/xxxx-xxxx/Android/data/<my.package>/files/` path. One doubt here that can we write outside to App directory like anywhere in SD card.

Comment: Using your `File[] filesDirectory = context.getExternalFilesDirs(null);` and `File[] Dirs = ContextCompat.getExternalFilesDirs(this, null); `

Comment: Yes, You can you have to create substring from you app package path. it will give you root directory, using this  directory path you can create your own folder. 

 private String getRootOfExternalStorage(File file) {
        if (file == null)
            return null;
        String path = file.getAbsolutePath();

        return path.replaceAll("/Android/data/" + getPackageName() + "/files", "");
    }